# I want to condition prompt and use it too in a CASE or ifthenelse and getting QE-DEF-0260 and QE-DEF-0261 errors in COGNOS

Tags: if-statement, case, prompt, cognos

```
case
when (?pAccountingMonth? = 'Monthly’)
then ([Prior YYYYMM])
else (?pAccountingMonth?)
end
```

What is wrong with above case statement?  I get similar errors using if then else

Comment: Where are you using this expression? Is it a filter or within a data item?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the right single quote in `'Monthly’`. Do you see anything weird? just put a regular single quote there.

I copied and pasted your code and was getting an error but it worked after fixing the single quote